# change color of pgfplots multiline stacked bar plot based on row

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to make the color of a stacked bar chart (like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349433/how-to-create-a-multiline-timeline)) depend on the data (like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368299/color-bars-dots-in-a-pgfplots-plot-based-on-data)) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438563/changing-colors-in-plot-pgfplots-loading-data-from-pgfplotstable).

So far, here is what I have, but I don't know how to access the "color" column of the data to make the bar plot of a particular row that color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% read in table
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
author,startyear,endyear,color
abc,1530,1570,red
def,1560,1570,green
ghi,1560,1660,blue
}\loadedtable


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  nodes near coords xbar stacked configuration/.style={},
  nodes near coords style={font=\footnotesize},
  xbar stacked,
  xmin=1500,
  bar width=0.2cm,
  axis lines=left,
  width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
  ytick=\empty,
]

\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table [col sep=comma,x=startyear, y expr=-\coordindex]{\loadedtable};
\addplot +[
   nodes near coords,
   nodes near coords align={anchor=west},
   point meta=explicit symbolic] table[col sep=comma,x expr=\thisrow{endyear}-\thisrow{startyear}, y expr=-\coordindex,meta=author]{\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit: Sorry for the previous answer. I was complete wrong about the stack bar plot function. I edit the answer to make it work.

This is not perfect solution, but it is working finally. Now the plot are drawn from single `.txt` file. The `\addplot` commands are only used to draw the axis and define the bar position (you can not have a legend for different bars). The bar is actually draw using `\draw` command after the `\addplot`. Using `\foreach` and `datatool` package commands to draw a thick line with different colors to represent the bar. You have any number rows in the `.txt` file, specify the color for each bar, define the vertical location using column `y`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{a.txt}
author,startyear,endyear,y,color
abc1,1520,1570,6,red
def1,1540,1590,5,green
abc2,1550,1575,4,yellow
def2,1560,1570,3,green
ghi1,1560,1660,2,blue
ghi2,1620,1660,1,purple
jkl1,1590,1650,0,orange
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DTLloaddb{tablea}{a.txt}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\DTLrowcount{tablea}}{
\edef\tempi{\noexpand\DTLassign{tablea}{\i}{\csname xst\i\endcsname=startyear,\csname xed\i\endcsname=endyear,\csname yp\i\endcsname=y,\csname col\i\endcsname=color}}\tempi}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  nodes near coords xbar stacked configuration/.style={},
  nodes near coords style={font=\footnotesize},
  xmin=1500,
  bar width=0.2cm,
  xbar stacked,
  stack negative=on previous,
  axis lines=left,
  width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
  ytick=\empty,
]
\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table [col sep=comma,x=startyear, y=y]{a.txt};
\addplot[
   nodes near coords,draw=none,
   nodes near coords align={anchor=west},
   point meta=explicit symbolic] table [col sep=comma,x expr=\thisrow{endyear}-\thisrow{startyear}, y expr=\thisrow{y},meta index=0]{a.txt};

\foreach \i in {1,...,\DTLrowcount{tablea}}{
\edef\tempii{\noexpand\draw [line width=8pt,\csname col\i\endcsname] (axis cs:\csname xst\i\endcsname,\csname yp\i\endcsname) -- (axis cs:\csname xed\i\endcsname,\csname yp\i\endcsname);}\tempii}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tom! What if I want to have a red abc1 followd by green def1 then red abc2 and green def2? I.e., if I want it to respect an input order I provide?

Comment: I'm willing to add manually each line/row since there aren't many

Comment: @rrrrr I just show them as an example. You could do that by just use one file one row.

Comment: Ah, I see! thanks

Comment: @rrrrr You need also define the right order of color for each file.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @rrrrr You said you need red follow by green, and red, so you need define the `foreach` as `a/red,b/green,c/red,d/...`

Comment: @rrrrr each term in `foreach` means the table file name and bar color `name/color`.

Comment: Ok i see about the `foreach`! What is the purpose of "wholetable.txt"? seems it's not used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136921/discussion-between-rrrrr-and-tom).

Comment: @rrrrr I update the answer.

Comment: if I duplicate the code and try to make two plots in the same doc, it gives a "Missing control sequence inserted." error; any idea what this could be?

Comment: @rrrrr I should put the `DTLassign` command in the preamble. I changed the code.

Comment: thanks, that works for two plots of the same `a.txt`, but I have issue when i have an `a.txt` and a different `b.txt` (please see my posted answer below). Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add multiple of these plots in the same file (from @Tom):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{a.txt}
  author,startyear,endyear,y,color
  abc1,1520,1570,6,red
  def1,1540,1590,5,green
  abc2,1550,1575,4,yellow
  def2,1560,1570,3,green
  ghi1,1560,1660,2,blue
  ghi2,1620,1660,1,purple
  jkl1,1590,1650,0,orange
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{b.txt}
  author,startyear,endyear,y,color
  jkl1,1590,1650,0,orange
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DTLloaddb{tablea}{a.txt}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\DTLrowcount{tablea}}{
\edef\tempi{\noexpand\DTLassign{tablea}{\i}{\csname axst\i\endcsname=startyear,\csname axed\i\endcsname=endyear,\csname ayp\i\endcsname=y,\csname acol\i\endcsname=color}}\tempi}
\DTLloaddb{tableb}{b.txt}
\foreach \j in {1,...,\DTLrowcount{tableb}}{
\edef\tempj{\noexpand\DTLassign{tableb}{\j}{\csname bxst\j\endcsname=startyear,\csname bxed\j\endcsname=endyear,\csname byp\j\endcsname=y,\csname bcol\j\endcsname=color}}\tempj}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  nodes near coords xbar stacked configuration/.style={},
  nodes near coords style={font=\footnotesize},
  xmin=1500,
  bar width=0.2cm,
  xbar stacked,
  stack negative=on previous,
  axis lines=left,
  width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
  ytick=\empty,
]
\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table [col sep=comma,x=startyear, y=y]{a.txt};
\addplot[
   nodes near coords,draw=none,
   nodes near coords align={anchor=west},
   point meta=explicit symbolic] table [col sep=comma,x expr=\thisrow{endyear}-\thisrow{startyear}, y expr=\thisrow{y},meta index=0]{a.txt};

\foreach \i in {1,...,\DTLrowcount{tablea}}{
\edef\tempii{\noexpand\draw [line width=8pt,\csname acol\i\endcsname] (axis cs:\csname axst\i\endcsname,\csname ayp\i\endcsname) -- (axis cs:\csname axed\i\endcsname,\csname ayp\i\endcsname);}\tempii}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    nodes near coords xbar stacked configuration/.style={},
    nodes near coords style={font=\footnotesize},
    xmin=1500,
    bar width=0.2cm,
    xbar stacked,
    stack negative=on previous,
    axis lines=left,
    width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
    ytick=\empty,
  ]
  \addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table [col sep=comma,x=startyear, y=y]{b.txt};
  \addplot[
     nodes near coords,draw=none,
     nodes near coords align={anchor=west},
     point meta=explicit symbolic] table [col sep=comma,x expr=\thisrow{endyear}-\thisrow{startyear}, y expr=\thisrow{y},meta index=0]{b.txt};
  
  \foreach \j in {1,...,\DTLrowcount{tableb}}{
  \edef\tempjj{\noexpand\draw [line width=8pt,\csname bcol\j\endcsname] (axis cs:\csname bxst\j\endcsname,\csname byp\j\endcsname) -- (axis cs:\csname bxed\j\endcsname,\csname byp\j\endcsname);}\tempjj}
  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: j was changing from 1 to maximum rows number in tableb as well, So the macro name was same for for tablea and tableb (e.g. \xst1, \xed1, \yp1, \col1 etc...) , So you need use different names for tableb e.g.  `\edef\tempj{\noexpand\DTLassign{tableb}{\j}{\csname bxst\j\endcsname=startyear,\csname bxed\j\endcsname=endyear,\csname byp\j\endcsname=y,\csname bcol\j\endcsname=color}}\tempj}`

Comment: And `foreach` loop in second tikz need to be changed as well. `\edef\tempjj{\noexpand\draw [line width=8pt,\csname bcol\j\endcsname] (axis cs:\csname bxst\j\endcsname,\csname byp\j\endcsname) -- (axis cs:\csname bxed\j\endcsname,\csname byp\j\endcsname);}\tempjj}`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'll leave my edited reply above, unless you'd like to incorporate into your answer